# HDMI not detected on Asus Tuf fx505 GTX 1660T

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, hdmi, asus

HDMI not detected on Asus Tuf fx505 (BIOS version - 310), GTX 1660TI, Ryzen 7 3750h ubuntu 18.04 5.3.0-45-generic.

Additionally, I have issue with screen flashing after suspend mode. Tried adding: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.blacklist=1"` as suggested in https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Suspend-resume-problems-on-Ubuntu-18-04/td-p/6072410 No result.

`nvidia-sm`i shows:

[nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YVWC.png)

`dmesg` errors:

```
[    0.446580] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP0.SWUS], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/dswload2-160)
[    0.446586] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-221)
[    0.446588] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)
[    0.446589] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP0.SWUS.SWDS], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/dswload2-160)
[    0.446592] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-221)
[    1.369200] pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter.
[    1.470598] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[    1.471315] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0xbd326000-0xbd329fff]
[    1.471323] tpm_crb: probe of MSFT0101:00 failed with error -16
[   71.781264] FAT-fs (sda1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[  193.069345] ucsi_ccg 1-0008: failed to reset PPM!
[  193.069353] ucsi_ccg 1-0008: PPM init failed (-110)
[  803.091435] ucsi_ccg 1-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
[  848.269734] ucsi_ccg 1-0008: PPM NOT RESPONDING
[  848.269745] PM: dpm_run_callback(): ucsi_ccg_resume+0x0/0x20 [ucsi_ccg] returns -110
[  848.269748] PM: Device 1-0008 failed to resume: error -110
```

`xrandr` :

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080    120.04*+  48.01  
   1680x1050    120.04  
   1280x1024    120.04  
   1440x900     120.04  
   1280x800     120.04  
   1280x720     120.04  
   1024x768     120.04  
   800x600      120.04  
   640x480      120.04
```

I am fighting near 4 days with such problem. Tried HDMI port not detected on Ubuntu 18.04 , different versions of nvidia drivers - NO Result.

Hope someone could help me with this.

Comment: see my solution here, to use the 515 proprietary drivers. (despite many here saying not to do that or that it it not necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Found solution here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-xconfig-doesnt-do-what-i-want-it-to-nor-does-nvidia-settings/107883/7

Main steps:

1. delete */etc/X11/xorg.conf*
2. modify */usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf*

`Driver "amdgpu"` -> `Driver "modesetting"`

3. inside /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf add

`Option "PrimaryGPU" "Yes"`

4. create two files **optimus.desktop** in  */etc/xdg/autostart/* and */usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart/*  with content:

optimus.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Optimus
Exec=sh -c "xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0; xrandr --auto"
NoDisplay=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=DisplayServer
```

After, function can be checked in terminal:

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia glxinfo | grep vendor
```

The output should be something with `Nvidia`

It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer you found! I had the exact same issue and the fix worked after a reboot.