# No HDMI output for Wayland, bad output or half screen for X11, 22.04 and ASUS Ryzen FX505DT TUF

Tags: display, 22.04, hdmi, asus

hdmi works fine for HP Envy (two different laptops, one with 22.04 and one with 20.04 ), and another one with exactly same (Clonezilla) partition of ASUS TUF 22.04.

On a smaller monitor HDMI I can get, switching to xorg (X11) full screen but severely bad quality. I did have half a screen earlier on. System bogged down a lot too, mouse and keyboard. On a larger 60" TV, nothing Wayland or X11.

Nothing for either on Wayland.

nothing in BIOS for HDMI. Secure boot is disabled. Legacy enabled.

https://www.asus.com/us/supportonly/FX505DT/HelpDesk_BIOS/
BIOS 3.16 latest I have it.

other threads here go back to 2016 on this sort of problem.

gnome is 42.4
kernel is 5.15.0-48-generic
updates up to date.

side note: sad that this is a gaming laptop.. and a huge improvement over the other struggles with the Envy's over three years (you name it, I've had it).

Comment: I put in nouveau.blacklist=1 into grub and with X11 got the full screen, but shocking quality.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224668/hdmi-not-detected-on-asus-tuf-fx505-gtx-1660t

Comment: following that thread  cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf
Section "OutputClass"
        Identifier "AMDgpu"
        MatchDriver "amdgpu"
        Driver "amdgpu"
        Driver "modesetting"
EndSection
but there is no /etc/X11/xorg.conf for me
plus I am not using the 3rd party nvidia drivers, just the ones that come with Ubuntu installation. and there is no /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf add  here either.

Comment: and same loggiing into gnome classic. it is 1/th of a screen showing now. I also bumped down the resolution even to 800X600, same

Comment: I booted into 2X Ubuntu Live USB.. 22.04 and the hdmi screen worked fine, 22.04 and it was blank. so I guess I will have to hope for updates sometime.

Comment: I got HDMI, booting into LiveUSB for 20.04 , but not for 22.04 . I presume I will have to patiently wait for any updates.

Answer (score 0):

well, to all those who say use the default open source drivers and 'there is no need to use the  proprietary drivers' , I say bollocks

I probably had to download the dpkg file from
https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers

sudo dpkg -i amdgpu-install_22.20.50200-1_all.deb

amdgpu-install

then software, the blue one, additional drivers, choose the top one, proprietary 515 non open source.

reboot

and hdmi is now working.

Comment: other inspirations from 

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: I should give myself my own bounty for that. now for a Clonezilla backup, just in case... the sounds works through hdmi too.

Comment: "515" is a NVIDIA graphics drivers version and if it's being offered then you also have a Nvidia card. And yes, for those proprietary drivers ARE recommended if not sometimes required. However, you mentioned the proprietary AMD overlay that it's NOT necessary at all.

Comment: I hear you, and I am slightly out of my depth with it, but the 'additional drivers' was blank with the default installation. and with 22.04 there was no hdmi output at all. I took  a lot of effort, and taking the jump. which many posts here over many years now, have said to not do. I also have options there for the open source drivers, I only chose the top one for 515 as suggested in the link there.

Comment: not a 'card 'as such, it is a 4gb seperate graphics chip in a laptop. VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series. wow a downvote for solving a problem.

Comment: The -1 is likely because the answer isn't useful. I'll add misleading to that. What you have is a very common hybrid graphics (AMD+Nvidia not so common) and you're misunderstanding almost everything. The Nvidia is a discrete GPU so an addon card, not just a chip; AMD graphics is integrated GPU, part of the CPU. Nvidia needs proprietary drivers and especially for using external monitors that typically are only connected to the dGPU. AMD does NOT require any proprietary drivers. So, your "answer" is wrong about that. What changed was installing the Nvidia drivers, end of story.

Comment: well I am happy if you can answer my OP question, to Clonezilla back to before I install the propietary drivers and you can guide me though it, there were, to my memory NO additional drivers on a raw Ubuntu installation. only be choosing them AFTER the new drivers could I get a solution. the specs for my laptop also state 4gb video, so is that on the integrated chip as you assume to be the case? it is not shared memory   has two fans. so the question is, is this laptop integrated graphics OR similar to an add on PCI-E card on a desktop. the latter benefiting from propietary drivers.

Comment: from https://www.asus.com/uk/Laptops/For-Gaming/TUF-Gaming/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX505DD-DT-DU/techspec/
NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650, 4GB GDDR5

Comment: and I am guessing that dGPU stands for dedicated Graphics Processing Unit.

Comment: Discrete graphics cards have dedicated memory, integrated don't, they use assigned memory from the system, as always. Since many releases ago Ubuntu allows the installations of 3rd party drivers during the OS installation (it's an option that users can select and you should have done that). When not selected the same drivers can be installed *a posteriori*. And, AGAIN, the NVIDIA ones are the ONLY drivers you should have installed. (...)

Comment: (...) AMD or Intel graphics work with open-source drivers already installed, always. It makes no sense to install `amdgpu-pro` unless you have 1. an actual card, not a GPU in an CPU -and- you need to use it for 3D modeling, mining (no longer applicable), machine learning or similar tasks. Not even for games the proprietary overlay provides any noticeable advantage. End of story.

Comment: why do you draw a distinction between a separate GPU in a laptop (which I am assuming from the specs and the dedicated 4Gb memory it has) and a card in a slot in a desktop? mine has dedicated memory, is that not clear? it is a dGPU surely.  I will leave it there, I must be trying your patience, and in any case, my answer solved my problem.

Comment: **AGAIN, what solved in your case was installing the NVIDIA drivers, NOT the AMD ones.** And there's a distinction because in laptops with this configuration it's called hybrid graphics (for the 3rd time) that, in Windows and with Windows drivers, toggle seemingly according to the demand: The iGPU doing most of the work while using much less energy and the dGPU comes to life *only* when there's a software demand for it (but then uses a lot more energy) . The same almost works in Linux but usually we have to reboot.

Comment: thanks for your patience... I'll look into it tomorrow.

Comment: leaving it for now... but I do notice now right click on an app in dock and it has option to 'launch using discrete graphics card'. so that begs the question if my default running amdgpu is using that 'other' cards memory or shared memory. I'd guess these things are all designed for windows 'gamers'.

Comment: Thank you, installing the amd drivers worked for me. There were no additional drivers showing in the the "blue" software and updates, but after a reboot sound was back for HDMI. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: mind you, it only works for Ubuntu Wayland or Classic Wayland login, not for Classic or 'Ubuntu'.